# Restarting by clicking "Restart Now" or normal restart doesn't install updates

Tags: windows, updates, reboot

After checking and installing Updates over Windows Update I get a dialog to restart Windows:

[image: http://prntscr.com/7wpns1]

When I restart it doesn't install any updates!

How can i fix this?

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is.  Are you asking if there is a difference in completing the install process whether you click the Restart Now button vs. wait and do a manual restart later (there isn't; that's just advice and a convenient button)?  When you click the button, what makes you think installation is not being completed?  In most cases, restarting is just for cleanup and making changes that couldn't be applied to files in use.  It can be very fast.

Comment: do you get a message during reboot that Windows has to revert changes? if yes, copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\cbs to your desktop, zip the folder, upload the zip (onedrive) and post a link here.

Answer (score 0):

This happened sometimes with Windows. I can't find direct reference on the Microsoft's site, but in a few words - you need to `Shutdown` computer instead of `Restart`. This usually happens with CPU microcode updates and require to turn computer off instead of reboot.